# Mapping a Map with Dynamic Keys in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to store this kind of data inside an Elasticsearch index

```
{
  "id": "5644596f9bf67301645999d9",
  "headline": "Scientists Look Beyond Solar System to Study Planet",
  "renditions": {
    "baseImage": {
      "height": 933,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 1400
    },
    "preview": {
      "height": 500,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 400
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "height": 150,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 125
    }
  }
}
```

However the mapping keeps adding unique blocks for all the different children of "renditions".

Ideally, I would define a type of child for "renditions" then assert that all objects under it should be like that.

Is this possible?

I've looked into Dynamic Mappings but I've got a bit confused with it all...

Comment: Can you change the structure of your data? Or do you have to use that form?

Comment: Ideally it would stay this way, as it's stored in Mongo too, so sharing the same model structure would the be the easiest.

What would you suggest if I did change the model? Storing it as an array?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Something like, `"renditions":[{ "key_name": "thumbnail", "value": {...} },...]`, maybe. In that case you would probably want to use a `nested` type.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this mapping with dynamic templates:

```
PUT /test

PUT /test/_mapping/test
{
   "properties": {
      "id": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "headline": {
         "type": "string"
      }
   },
   "dynamic_templates": [
      {
         "renditions_objects": {
            "mapping": {
               "dynamic": "strict",
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                  "height": {
                     "type": "integer"
                  },
                  "href": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "mimetype": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "width": {
                     "type": "integer"
                  }
               }
            },
           "match_mapping_type": "object",
           "path_match": "renditions.*"            
         }      
      }
   ]
}
```

The line

```
"dynamic": "strict",
```

makes sure that you cannot index any document where extra fields are present. The process fails if you try to index something like this:

```
POST /test/test
{
  "id": "5644596f9bf67301645999d9",
  "headline": "Scientists Look Beyond Solar System to Study Planet",
  "renditions": {
    "baseImage": {
      "height": 933,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 1400,
      "dummy": 12
    },
    "preview": {
      "height": 500,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 400
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "height": 150,
      "href": "www.imgur.com/animage",
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "width": 125
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the extra `dummy` key in `baseImage`. It will fail with error:

```
{
   "error": "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [dummy] within [renditions.baseImage] is not allowed]",
   "status": 400
}
```

If you want to make it a little relaxed and allow such documents to be indexed, but don't want the extra fields to be indexed, then set `dynamic` to `false`. This will not cause any failure while indexing such documents, also the extra field will be present in the `_source` field. However, that field will not be indexed and you won't be able to perform any query or filter on that field. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, that works! However when I look at the mapping it still have 3 blocks, one for baseImage, preview & thumbnail. My original plan was to make it so it wouldn't need to create a new block for each Key name. Is this possible?

Comment: Mapping out, for reference - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/petersow/c1a926064d36f88dbc82/raw/a6cbe6c92eb986dcda7cc801550fb494d57526f7/gistfile1.txt